# Can you train primates to perform every day jobs that humans perform today?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, alternate-worlds, law

I want to know how / if we could train monkeys to do a variety of human tasks. Is it possible to teach monkeys human trades and set them free throughout major cities to do jobs and interact with humans?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100843/discussion-on-question-by-liam-parent-can-you-make-monkeys-human).

Comment: For those answering your question some indication of the sort of 'trades' you're considering here would be helpful, shoe shine boy? carpenter? rocket scientist? what are you actually after here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not without majorly altering the monkeys to the point where they aren't monkeys anymore and its a new subspecies. They aren't smart enough. The expression 'Monkey see, monkey do' comes to mind - they can be trained, yes. They can be trained to do things. But there's no way for them to go 'Planet of the Apes' on us. Thankfully.

Comment: I find this quite disappointing. So I could train a monkey to shoot a gun still right?

Comment: You can train a monkey to shoot a gun. At that point you run several risks, including the monkey *shooting you*, but can train a monkey to shoot a gun.

Comment: Perfect muahahaha!

Comment: @LiamParent: [Train a monkey to shoot a gun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhxqIITtTtU), relatively well-known real-life footage.

Comment: The monkey would also likely not fully understand what the gun was doing, would have no idea what to do if it jammed or stopped working, and, as @Halfthawed commented, would probably shoot fairly indiscriminately.

Comment: @AlexP That footage is fake - it was a promo video for Rise of Planet of the Apes.
[Here is the cure for your disappointment](https://youtu.be/Ekd-2bbobkw?t=128).

Comment: @AlexP Chimps aren't monkeys, they're apes. The difference is that they're smarter, and they don't have a tail.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: Joke. The video clip is known to be part of a promotional campaign for a film featuring apes doing battel with humans. I thought that most people knew this. Perhaps I live in a different bubble...

Comment: All fake news we are monkeys therefor we can shoot guns! hahaha!

Comment: OP is asking for domesticated monkeys which don't exist... yet, +1.

Comment: Why is everyone hating POTA so badly?

Answer (score 9):

[japan do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjHQrAVT5yU) and most south east asian country also train monkey for certain activity, from picking coconut or other fruit to [street circuss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scYwoFEAEpk) to act like human like [riding bicycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kVW7G_-wz0),smoking, even as drug cartel, etc.

i dont know about japan but the training that i know though..... is pretty much would make animal lovers like PETA mad because it choke the monkey with chain to force them standing in two feet etc and pretty much torture them, picking coconut and drug cartel is more humane though because you give a treat as their payment ([yes they understand some kind of value](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meiU6TxysCg)) and not require them to standing in two feet.

also if you want the monkey into military they probably do better as grenade thrower because they naturally know how to do it.

and i just want to put this image just because

[image]

Comment: Yes they understand value, and one of the first things they do when given something of value is invent prostitution.

Comment: monkey prostitution yes plz haha

Comment: @LiamParent well.....it actually exist...... al though i only known ape prostitution for people that like kinky bestiality, i know you guys are joking but.....stuff like that exist in the dark corner of the world.....just saying.....

Comment: Monkeys are actually much worse grenade throwers than humans.  They have the strength for it, but are not nearly as accurate.  https://what-if.xkcd.com/44/

Comment: @Nosajimiki its says ape though not monkey specifically chimp each have different hand, and sure they may not better at throwing than human but they definitelly not worse at it, on the contrary i believe they have better aim or accuracy but not enough force or strength, judging from my observation of monkey throwing rock and their feces.

Comment: training a monkey to do one single task is a world of difference from getting them to the point they can hold down a trade job. You basically listing things we can also train dogs to do. your not trying to make a dancing bear you are trying to get a carpenter.

Comment: @john but you need to pay them to do the job, and street entertainer is still a job anyway, i even list drug cartel there and the first video is japan monkey caffe maid which i consider as trade and interract with human, they even have penguin goes to market to buy stuff, and yes dog can do some of that, i heard some use dog as drug cartel too and i still consider that as job not personal entertainment to your pet.

Comment: @john oh yeah also trade usually mean exchanging stuff between parties or group or exchanging service or delivering stuff, usually if people mean carpentry (mostly about skilled labor) they refer to it as crafting rather than trade.

Comment: @LiJun Trade: noun, a skilled job, typically one requiring manual skills and special training. list of trade careers include carpenter, electrician, auto mechanic,plumber, ironworker, ect. https://work.chron.com/list-trade-careers-7833.html or see the wiki for tradesperson. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradesman but really I am done with this question until the OP clarifies what theywant.

Comment: @John but in wikipedia [Trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade)  "Trade involves the transfer of goods or services from one person or entity to another, often in exchange for money" and in [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trade) it say "the activity of buying and selling, or exchanging, goods and/or services between people or countries" and this [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trade.asp)

Comment: @john "Trade is a basic economic concept involving the buying and selling of goods and services, with compensation paid by a buyer to a seller, or the exchange of goods or services between parties" even in this comment OP even want monkey prostitution and military use in other comment which i include in my answer are that considered as tradesman?

Comment: @LiJun they are actually much worse than humans.  Their shoulder design prevents them from throwing more than 20mph whereas a 12 year old Little League pitcher can average 60-70mph. https://scholar.harvard.edu/ntroach/evolution-throwing

Comment: @Nosajimiki yeah thats why i say they dont have enough force or strength in their throwing, but accuracy is debatable though at least i believe they are not bad at it, what two of your link has provide is pretty much about throwing force, and you dont need to throw grenade like throwing rock or sling that specifically aim to hit or knock a person.

Comment: It's about range, not force.  At that speed, the best range a chimp can get is about 8 meters at a perfect 45 degree arc. However, their accuracy is also so bad that they instinctively only throw things at ranges of 2 meters or less when trying to hit something.  (Even at this range, they only have a 10% accuracy against a roughly person sized target).  Since most grenades have a 5 meter kill radius and a 15 meter casualty radius, you might as well just rig them up as suicide bombers.

Answer (score 8):

You can train apes to do human jobs, but I doubt it would be worth the trouble.

Apes can understand the concept of work and payment, but their ability to grasp complex tasks is, on average, much lower than that of humans. They can also be moody, prone to distraction, and have their own personality traits that differ significantly from those of typical humans. Chimpanzees, for instance, are very aggressive and nearly impossible to control.

Instead of thinking of them as trained animals, think of them as severely mentally handicapped humans with serious personality disorders. They can be put to work, but in many cases this will prove a liability.

Comment: True. They can be tamed, but they will still remain wild animals. Just like a wolf can be tamed and trained, but will never get close to the behavior of a dog. In order to do that you need many many generations of domestication (hundreds, maybe thousands of years), and the end result will be a completely new species.

Answer (score 3):

You can do whatever you want in the fictional world but you need to understand that they will not be monkeys in the way we know them in this reality. They have no sense of value in anything beyond basic family or troop relationships, so “money” means nothing to them. Damaging property, stealing, giving things away, will never be concepts true monkeys can understand. They won’t arrive to work on time because they don’t know what time means. They will do whatever makes them feel good.

In your alternate world, you will have to give your monkeys a higher IQ and an ability to understand abstract thoughts, and to reciprocate moral values. The basic concept of a “troop” exists with real monkeys, and that could be developed in your story into an understanding of citizenship and civic duty after their intelligence is improved.

Again you can’t pretend these are “real monkeys” as we know them in this reality. If being “real monkeys” is crucial to your story, then the answer is simply, no.

Answer (score 2):

Teach no

genetically engineer (uplift), then teach, yes.

but uplifting a species is still way beyond our ability you would need severely advanced genetic engineering, likely generations away. Our first uplift will also be a more intelligent species likely an ape (although we could drive the rest of apes extinct before we get there), lastly our first uplift will also be largely trail and error, so they will spend a long time, generations, in the testing phase.

Comment: Genetic engineering isn't needed, most (actually, all) of what would be needed can be achieved by selective breeding to produce a properly domesticated species, less aggressive, more compliant, etc, at least some of the desired characteristics can be achieved just by breeding for retention of juvenile characteristics into adulthood.

Comment: @Pelinore to get usable levels of intelligence it is going to take hundreds of thousands of generations of selective breeding, at a minimum. millions is more likely. you basically have ot get to human levels of intelligence, so you are looking at more time than hte human species has been around.

Comment: For a most simple tasks & jobs you don't need any more intelligence than chimps already have, what you do need are changes to social & (what for people we'd call) 'personality' traits, what we call 'domestication' in most species we've done it to & all things that have been demonstrated as possible breed for within very few generations if you've the resources & manpower to go at it properly.

Comment: @ you really do need more intelligence than chimps for most jobs, for one thing you need to be intelligent enough to do a job rather than wondering away looking for food an females. You need to be able to see the long term benefits of the job. And the OP specifies a trade, which means skilled labor which is even harder so you need human levels of intelligence. Also starting with monkeys not chimps which is a big difference.

Comment: No you really don't, what jobs do you think the OP is talking about, something that requires a PHD? if it can be trained to do a thing under supervision then you don't need more intelligence than it has you just need it to be less easily distracted & more focused on the tasks it's taught, no more intelligence is needed for that, just different social & psychological traits so that once set a task it's been trained to it will stick to it rather than becoming distracted & return to it after the distraction has passed if it is distracted.

Comment: first a trade would be something like a carpenter, aka skilled labor. second if it needs non-stop intensive supervision you could save money just by hiring the supervisor to do the job, a chimp could not even be trained to be a janitor, and monkeys are a long long way from chimps. If you want an animal that is not easily distracted you can either breed it for a single task or you need intelligence so it can assess and override itself. organisms are not robots, you cannot just program in subroutines, especially not through just selective breeding.

Comment: ^ That's for simple jobs I can imagine a chimp being trained to do (supermarket trolley boy, that sort of thing), I'm assuming that's what theOP is on about & just wants them doing it unsupervised, if the OP wants them to be car mechanics that's a different kettle of fish entirely of course, you probably need @ least the intelligence of an 8 year old & maybe more for that

Comment: @Pelinore Intelligence is a double edged sword the more intelligent the animal the less predictable its behavior is, the less likely it is to do what you want. One of the ways we made dogs more easily trainable was making them dumber.

Comment: ***second if it needs non-stop intensive supervision*** read what I've said again, my point from the get go has been it's likely you can domesticate & breed the traits into them so they **Don't** need supervision within 10 or fewer generations & for many minor jobs & tasks they only need **that** & not more intelligence.

Comment: ***Intelligence is a double edged sword the more intelligent*** OK so now I have to ask, wtf are you talking about? I've not said anything anywhere about needing **more** intelligence, have you actually read what I said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100862/discussion-between-john-and-pelinore).

Answer (score 0):

We are still at the stage that we don't know most of the molecular mechanism that how our body works. Even one day we know that, we still don't know how brain-to-mind works. So we can never be sure whether we can train monkey (or any specie that have a complex enough brain) to do advanced human things. Without theory support, the only thing we can do is to try and try like Edison did.

For complex and mysterious system like brain/mind, every thing is possible, it just still doesn't happen. Maybe a new special method of stimulation/training, or maybe a few gene modifications that make monkey trainable with existing methods. Any of this will triger another revolution like the 20th century physics did.

But the key is that that is not enough. You train moneys to be like human, then they will demand rights and more, and finally get that through wars just like we did. They won't work without demand like you expected. They are just us, and there are already enough us and we don't need more. So the even more hard question is how to train money to be human with no demands which I suppose is impposible.